# jboss Caught Secure FTP Exception

Tags: ftp, jboss

I`m using Jboss 4.4 on top of RHEL 4.7 and when implementing a FTP session my log continually throws tihs kind of error:

org.jboss.internal.soa.esb.util.SecureFtpImpl] Caught Secure FTP Exception

So far it`s not my application but rather Jboss'es

How can I debug such error or has this been reported as a bug?

Regards,

arvychile

Answer (score 0):

Need more information.  The message you're getting should be followed by a stack trace showing the exception itself.